# Surface Librarybar with scrollbars

Tags: scrollbar, scrollviewer, surface

We have a library bar filled with items, which can be dragged from and dropped onto it. Now the client wishes to see something like a scrollbar or arrows on the side, to have an indication if items are outside of the visible port.

As you can see in the librarybar template below, it contains a surface scrollviewer. Yet I don't seem to be able to reveal these scrollbars.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

The librarybar template:
http://pastebin.com/QVnvqbNm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it. Answer was easier then expected. Found out that the scrollbars were cleanly removed, but all properties regarding it were still present. Kind of misleading.

Easiest way to solve:

1. Open expression blend.
2. Insert SurfaceScrollViewer
3. Open Template from the SurfaceScrollViewer
4. Copy SurfaceScrollbars & necessary templates to the templates/resources 
   from your library bar
5. Adjust the templates to meet your requirements